# Keys, codes and patterns

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

> My flatmate always forgets his key, so now we have installed a small locker outside the room where a spare is located. So that my flatmates doesn't forget the code we made this small riddle for him, if he can find the pattern he **finds the missing number**. The missing number is also the code for unlocking the locker. Please help him, he forgot his key (and the pattern) again....

[image]

Hint:

> The pattern starts at the top left corner.

Hint:

> If you sum first one number, secondly three numbers, thridly five numbers and lastly seven numbers the pattern should be clear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing number is

> 131

The reason is that

> [image]
>  as denoted by the red lines, each group sums to 311

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> 295

Reason

> If we consider the top row being the sum of some of the
>  12 numbers below we get the following:
>  [image] 
>  where each number is being used precisely once and the different colors corresponds to one of the four numbers in the top row

Comment: You're definitely in the right direction. The pattern includes the sum of numbers, but the numbers which are summed are arranged in a clear pattern and not randomly arranged over the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Answer :

> $331$

Because :

> If we observe first column there is pattern : 
> 311 ( $three$ one time and $one$ two times) 
> 133 ( $one$ one times and $three$ two times ) 
> 113 ($one$ two times and $three$ one times)
> So , as we can see above there is no $3$ two times in start so i think there should be 
>  $331$

Comment: Good try, but all sixteen numbers are needed to find the pattern which leads to the question mark!

Comment: @tyui  rot13(jr arrq gb nqq nyy pbyhza fhz naq naq gura fhogenpg jvgu pbyhza 1 ,vs fb nafjre jvyy or 1 (557-556 = 1))

Comment: rot13(fhogenpgvba vf abg arrqrq gb svaq gur cnggrea)

Comment: "Same result we will get if we add rows as well" No Shit Sherlock... rot13(V'z abg fnlvat: fhzz bs nyy ahzoref = ? )

Comment: rot13(v nz pbashfr yvggyr ovg , ohg yrg vg or fbzr bar ryfr jvyy tvir nafjre bs guvf v nz abg fb tbbq va znguf :C)

Answer (score 1):

We start from the top. The sum of the first row is 315 + 165 + 145 +83 = 704. The sum of the second row is 133 + 13 + 3 + 1 = 150. The sum of the third row is 113 + 19 + 31 + 50 = 213. The sum of the fourth row is 12 + 2 + 32 = 46. If we subtract from the sum of the first row the sum of the other three rows, we have 704 - (150 + 213 + 46) = 295, so the missing number is 295.

Comment: that's not the missing number, but you're getting closer!